# restore mysql database

Tags: mysql, restore

I recieved a mysql backup without .dump as a extension from hosting provider. How do I restore that database somewhere else.

I am using linux box with mysql version 5.0 .

I have tried steps posted at [How do I restore a dump file from mysqldump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) but couldn't get through.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the database backup does not have a .dump extension, then what format is it on? Can you run it through "file" and find out what kind of file is it?

Comment: I got this from webhost4life admin control panel, when I did the backup of this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use phpmyadmin as a backend tool, use the 'import' feature. This is located in a popup box. To activate this popup click the 'SQL terminal' looking icon on the left hand plane and in the window which pops up head over to the 'import files' tab and upload the dump there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via command line very simple:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p < DUMP_FILENAME
```