# I need to restore a database (mysql) every 30 minutes using a cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm new to cron jobs and I need to restore a database (mysql) every 30 minutes. Is there a cron job command that can restore a database from a .sql file that's been gzipped?

Or do I need to create a php script to do this and create a cron job to call this script every thirty minutes?

Also, and this is a separate question but still related to cron jobs, I'm using a cron job to backup a different database once a day, gzip it and put it in a folder above the root. Is there a way to (automatically) delete anything older than a month? Or, at least, keep the most recent 20 backups and delete the rest?

There's not a lot of good tutorial out there on this subject other that random forum posts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding how to import a dump file, simply put a

```
mysql -u user -ppassword databasename < /path/to/dump.sql
```

into the cron job.

More details: [How do I restore a MySQL .dump file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file)

Comment: I understand the history in this Pekka, but would it be more efficient performing this method over `cat /path/to/file.sq/ | mysql -u root -ppassword`?

Comment: @Daryl I know too little about how Unix/Linux pipes through file data to say which way is more efficient! It may well be that your suggestion is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bash script to do this.

```
mysql -uPutYourUserHere -pPutYourPasswordHere PutYourUserHere_databaseName < database.sql
```

There isn't anything to automatically delete something. But you can do in your cron job:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -exec rm  {}\;
```

Comment: I meant a cron job to delete old backups. I think "automatically" was misleading. Will try your suggestion. Not really familiar with bash scripts I'm afraid.

Comment: find is a really powerful tool. sometimes if you just google "find delete month old" you will find the right answer.

Comment: I'm getting a error sent to me that says find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: I tried this on my mac and it worked find . -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

Comment: Note: there needs to be space between {} and \;

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can't handle the gzipped data directly, but it's trivial to pipe through gzcat and then pipe that to mysql:

```
gzcat name_of_file.sql.gz | mysql -u....
```