# Restore a MySQL Database and Files every 30 mins for a demo site

Tags: mysql, cron, backup, restore

Ok I read this post:

[I need to restore a database (mysql) every 30 minutes using a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027832/i-need-to-restore-a-database-mysql-every-30-minutes-using-a-cron-job)

and the answer was:

mysql -u user -ppassword databasename < /path/to/dump.sql

My question is will that erase the data that is already in the database?  I need to overwrite from a stored MySQL file.

I also then need to overwrite all the files in one directory with a restore directory using cron command.

This is for a joomla install... I have tried 2 different components for joomla to setup a demo site that refreshes every 30 mins but I could not get either of them working.

does anyone have a solution that will totally restore a directory on a cron command?

Answer (score 0):

Using the cron job to run a `.sql` file can do what you want. To replace all the data you'll have to add the table drop and creation statements to the file being executed. That will force the specific data that you want to be the only data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to skip dumping/importing and just swap the directories. As long as you do the whole mysql data directory, everything will work. Except if you have a master/slave setup. Shutdown mysql and make a copy of the mysql data directory. That will be your restore source going forward. Then setup a cron to do the following:

1. Make a copy of the mysql backup directory

   cp -R mysql.bak mysql.restore
2. Stop mysql
3. Swap the current mysql data directory with the restore directory

   mv mysql mysql.rm
   mv mysql.restore mysql
4. Start mysql
5. Clean mysql directory you just swapped

   rm mysql.rm

Mysql would only be down and unusable for a few seconds, depending on the size of your InnoDB tables.

Comment: You right a shell script to do all the steps, just like you would for an import. The setup cron to run the script every 30 minutes.