# Restore a specified database from a full backup via mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have a full backup MYSQL database.

```
mysqldump -u root --password=SSS -A > D:\bkps\mysql.sql
```

But, I need restore a specified database.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file

Comment: You'll have to extract the DDL/DML queries for your specific tables/dbs from the dump - mysqldump will process the whole file regardless of which tables/dbs you specify on the command line.

Comment: 1) Open it up and pull out only the information that you will need.
2) Save this text file.
3) Use the following command to feed back in the contents of a text file:

mysql --verbose --user=XXXXXXXX --password=XXXXXXXX DB_NAME < /PATH/TO/DUMPFILE.SQL

[link](http://www.patrickpatoray.com/?Page=30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a poor solution:

Delete all others lines of querys in the file and execute.

> `mysql dbname < backup.sql`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "mysql dbname < backup.sql"

Comment: A full backup contains ALL the DDL queries necessary to recreate the whole db server and will overwrite all databases that clash with what's in the dumb, regardless of which db you specify on the command line.

Comment: I found a poor solution at the moment: Delete all others querys in the file.

Comment: another option is to make another instance of mysql, import full backup, dump database you want , then import that into the real instance