# Unable to restore a MYSQL backup to a new Database

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I successfully created a `mysqldump` file `myDump.sql` of a `myDb1` database using guidelines from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) thread. Also I created a second database `myDb2`, navigated to the directory containing `myDump.sql` and trying to restore it into the new database `myDb2` but failing, Two methods I tried:

```
> mysql -u root -p myDb2 < myDump.sql;
> -- entered password
```

and:

```
> mysql -u root -p
mysql> -- entered password
mysql> USE myDb2;
mysql> SOURCE myDump.sql;
```

Both have the same error message:

```
ERROR:
ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in
 non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ' ■-'.
```

I'd also like to know if I need to use the same database name as the old db for the new one. I tried with a different and same names, but with this same result error.

Comment: try running `file myDump.sql`, what does it print? (if you are on linux)

Comment: @user4035 I don't have a linux. I use windows powerShell. Tried running myDump.sql as `mysql> SOURCE myDump.sql;` and I get `ERROR: Failed to open file 'myDump.sql', error: 2`

Comment: Is this file a text file? Check it with text editor.

Comment: @user4035 It is a `.sql` file, generated from running `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably caused by coding systems.
My dump file is generated using redirection (">") in powershell and I encountered the same problem. The output redirection generated a file with UTF-16 Little endian.

However, this can be solved by converting the dumpfile into utf-8. This can be done in emacs as:

***M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system***

Then save the file and import again.

The coding system of a file can be detected using GNU "file" utility, and it also available in windows and can be found here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm 
For future use, a better dump command like:

***mysqldump <dbname> -r <filename>***

Comment: Convert using notepad++ by add a new file and paste your SQL file and save it with another name and extension .sql. Viola! it automatically convert to UTF-8. Make sure in your settings->new document->unicode->UTF-8 is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `myDump.sql` file, it maybe a coding error in the file. These garbage characters cause this problem. Delete the garbage characters to solve the issue.

Open with Sequel Pro shows this

```
`í}k¯]ÇÝçðWÜ?øy«««_%c�sè;¶`Ìô hãEE¤"8Áü÷ô>ûqzW¯:êmX0`²¸yyëÔºµë¹êGw?û+þ{ð£»g¯ÿçw¯¿ºû/ß¾¹{ö/ï^}÷§oªô__ûöË7_ß'éÁªà¿¿{÷ÍÇ}ôý÷ßOo/ãoßL_¼ùÓG×?ûâÍ«×Óß¼ùãW¯/òÍGË?`
```