# Mysql source error on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mysql

I am working with mysql on `Ubuntu 15.04` and I have the following error while trying to `source` my `mysql script`.

```
ERROR: 
ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected.
```

I have tried to enable the binary-mode as `--binary-mode=1` but that doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you try to enable binary mode?

Comment: As in the following:

$>mysql -uroot -p --binary-mode=1

Comment: Have you checked the topics dealing with the same error here on SO and on dba.stackexchange.com? If yes, what exactly have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158367/enable-binary-mode-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/error-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538142/unable-to-restore-a-mysql-backup-to-a-new-database

Comment: Yes i did but that didn't help out either. I am trying to use utf-16 instead and see if it solves the problem.