# How can I read a .dump file with R ?

Tags: sql, r, mysql, sqldf

Suppose I have a .dump file that I would like to convert to a `data.frame` that I can then analyse in R. I know that `sqldf` allows us to use SQL commands on data frames but can we also use this or another package to read in .DUMP files?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) shows how to restore a .dump file with SQL but this syntax doesn't work in `sqldf`. Of course, I have no idea how to properly use SQL syntax, so it is likely my fault.

This is what I think the syntax should look like based on the post mentioned:

```
mysql create database mydb;
mysql use mydb;
mysql source dumpname.dump;
```

Comment: I presume your dump file is a list of `insert` statements. If possible, it's going to be much easier if you could get a csv dump straight off the database.

Comment: short answer: no, you can not use sqldf to parse your sql dump file