# SQL File Upload to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to databases. 
I want to upload a .sql file to a mysql server. However the database I want to update contains many .frm .myi .myd files. Should I delete those files and replace with the .sql?

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: frm myi and myd files are data files, I think it's not a good idea for you to delete them

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow as it's not a programming question.  Try http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not delete this files. The MyISAM system stores all the data in them.

I guess you got the `.sql` file by `mysqldump` utilite or something like this, so you need to restore it, don't you?

You could try something like this:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

And also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file)

Excuse me, if i misunderstood you, goodluck.