# Error 1049 (42000) : Unknown Database 'tryagain'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench, restore

```
Dim myProcess As New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.Start()
Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u root -p******* tryagain < C:\Users\deo\Documents\dumps\Dump20160221.sql ")
myStreamWriter.Close()
myProcess.WaitForExit()
myProcess.Close()
```

I am using a Mysql Server 5.7 and Viewing a the dbfiles via MysqlWorkbench.
What I am trying to do is Restore a .sql Database through the use of vb.net
But this error stops me to do this.

I searched a lot of related to my problem but no one matched to my error situation.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: How many databases does the dump file contain?

Comment: only one database file sir

Comment: Try adding `USE <database-name>` to the top of your dump file.

Comment: ("mysql -u root -padmin USE tryagain < C:\Users\deo\Documents\dumps\Dump20160221.sql ") so this will be my code sir?

Comment: Nope.  I said to add `USE` to your dump file.  The command line remains the same.

Comment: how to do that sir? can you show me the code?

Comment: Edit your `Dump20160221.sql` file and add `USE tryagain` to the top of the file.

Comment: Still having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your dump file is missing a `USE` statement at the top, which is causing MySQL to not find the database to which your script is referring.  Add the following line to the top of your dump file:

```
USE tryagain
```

Read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file) for more information.