# How to restore MySQL backup file using Runtime process

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to restore my backup data with this code but nothing 
is happening, it's just running my fileName:

> C:\DDDD\Backups\DDDD_BD_BackUp_file_2016-04-07_12-06-21.Bak

```
   String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysql", "--user=" + User, "--password="+pwd," -h"+host," --port"+port," <"+ fileName}; 
                    String executeCmd1="mysql -h "+  host + " --port "+ port +" -u "+ User +" --password="+pwd +" "+nameBase +" -r "+ fileName;

                    System.out.println(executeCmd);
                    /*NOTE: Executing the command here*/
                   Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
                     int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

                        /*NOTE: processComplete=0 if correctly executed, will contain other values if not*/
                     if (processComplete == 0) {
                           System.out.println("Restore Complete");
                       } else {
                           System.out.println("Restore Failure");
                       }

                    }} catch (Exception ex) {
                       System.out.println(ex.toString());
                    }
```

Comment: does '<' work on windows now?

Comment: yes i test it in command line and it's working /cmd

Comment: You should be able to do this directly from the command line rather than from the mysql shell, so you should be able to do it using a single execute command. See these for info: On [MySQLDump](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php) and [basic command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file).