# Restore MySQL database from .mysql file

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a `backup.mysql` file that I created using `mysqldump`.

How can I use that to restore the database? I opened the file in Sublime Text, and here is what its beginning looks like!

[image: file content]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore a MySQL .dump file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file)

Comment: .mysql is a strange extension for a dump created with mysqldump. Is it an SQL script ?

Comment: Aye it is, but that is what it produced!

Comment: Not duplicate. This isn't `.dump` file

Comment: @berty added image on file header

Comment: this is a dump. just with .mysql extension. not so uncommon, `mysql -u user -p dumpimportsinthisdatabase < dump.mysql` should work just fine. you have to create "dumpimportsinthisdatabase" database, if it doe not yet exist.

Comment: so it is ok to simply rename it?

Comment: @Ciwan extension has no effect; I wanted to be sure it was an SQL script

Comment: Thanks @berty got you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dump you produced is a SQL script you can run with any tool you want. As OP from this question [How do I restore a dump file from mysqldump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file), if you try to restore it with MySQL Administrator or other software providing specific backup/restore functions, it can throw an error because it asks for a particular format (his own format); but if the dump has been produced correctly, you can run it with any MySQL client, for example with the command line tool :

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p yourschema < ./path/to/the/script.mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, I renamed it to `.dump` and used your command above and it worked!

Comment: @Ciwan to be clear, extension has no effect; but .mysql is quite unusual and I wanted to be sure it was an SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your `backup.sql` file to the working directory: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`. (or whatever your path)
2. In your command prompt or terminal switch to the MySQL directory. `cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin` (or whatever your path)
3. Open the MySQL Database system `mysql –h localhost –u root` (or whatever your credentials)
4. You need to re-grant permissions: `GRANT ALL ON your_db_here.* to 'root'@'localhost';` (or whatever your credentials)
5. You need to re-create the database: `CREATE DATABASE your_db_here;`
6. Start using the database: `USE your_db_here;`
7. Import the dump file that you created: `source backup.mysql`
8. Using `DESCRIBE` commands and `"SELECT * FROM"` commands ensure that your database has been restored properly.