# Accidentally dropped table from mysql server

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL, and I accidentally dropped a table with approx 3gb worth of data. Good news, I think I have a backup file .dump. Now is there an easy way to import this file to my MySQL?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-dump-file-from-mysqldump

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql -u username -p databse_name < backup.sql
```