# Restore db backup with php web application

Tags: php, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin, yii2

unfortunately i lost my database a few days ago but luckily i had daily back up.

unfortunately i lost  my database(some of my data not whole db) a few days ago but luckily i have daily backup.Today i find out that i have to restore 180  huge database.
I need to compare every 180 databases(backups) with the current db(my db) and insert the data that is not any more in my db.
AT the beginning i want to use some application like(NAVICAT or db forge studio) but it's not possible that take a lot of time.
and also i wanted to compare the SQL test with each other and it's not possible too.

**now i have to build a  web application(PHP) to restore the databases but i don't know how**

i'll be appreciate if anyone help me.

thank you.

Comment: one thing to know about backups: if you don't know how to restore them, they aren't backups. the usual best-practice for mysql is doing a mysql-dump, and [restoring it via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-dump-file-from-mysqldump)
without knowing how _you_ did your backup, there's no way for us to help you restore it.

Comment: How many databases do you need to restore. Do you have backup of each database in separate file?

Comment: of course i can restore my back up
i don't know how can i restore 180 backups and here is my problem

Comment: Have a look at the MySQL Workbench application: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html

Comment: if you have 180 backup files, you could *loop* over them? also, you should do some full backups every now and then

Comment: 180 daily backup in a separate file

Comment: i get this backups from my host company
and i have no idea how they backuped

i wanna know can i write a web application with php and give this web application a array of my backup name and it restore automaticlly
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a large file, do not open it. Stream it.

```
$backup = fopen("yourBackUp.sql", "r");

// ...

fclose($backup);
```

If you have many files, use `GLOB`.

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/*.sql', GLOB_BRACE) as $sql) {
    $backup = fopen($sql, "r");

    // ...
}
```

If your DB is set-up correctly, you should not be able to insert duplicate rows.

```
while (($line = fgets($backup)) !== false)
    try {
        Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw($line);
    } catch ( Exception $e ) { 
        // duplicate row
    }
}
```

Without seeing what you have done and your programmatic issue, we cannot help.

Comment: i just received the backup files from my host company and i do nothing programmatic

Comment: "now i have to build a web application(PHP) to restore the databases" @John