# Migrating Very Large Data Set from Local Machine To AWS RDS (Aurora)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I had a question regarding migrating large data form my local machine to AWS RDS (Aurora DB). Basically I have local mysql database that has couple of tables with around 4GB of data. I need to replicate this data in AWS RDS. The approach I was thinking was to make INSERT call to the RDS but with this huge amount of data (32 million rows), the process would be costly. I did see some resources on exporting data from local and importing it in RDS but could not quite understand how it works. Does someone have a good idea about this and advice me on what would be the best process. PS: the data only exist on local machine and not in any servers.

Comment: Are you saying it would be costly because of I/O? 4GB of data really isn't that much, I would lean towards just a normal `mysqldump` and import.

Comment: Any documentation you can provide for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-dump-file-from-mysqldump

Answer (score 0):

Dump a CSV extract into S3 then use an AWS migration tool, I.e. see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html